# open a activity hidden with a second class without ui

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, hidden

I hidden the main activity with "moveTaskToBack (true);"
as I return to open main activity from a second class without UI

this is my second class without ui.

```
package com.example.eriktux.alarmita;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, android.content.Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Despierta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: please correct your text. Anybody can't understand what is your problem.

Comment: excuse me, I'm using google translate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `static` method inb your activity. Something like:

```
public static void show(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

And call this method from your class without UI. Just use `MainActivity.show();`

Comment: thanks, but "this" and "startActivity" underlined in red.   :(